# Unable to Click Button with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to click on the settings button in Google but I am struggling with the page.click() method because I do not know what class or id to use to navigate to the tools button.
[image: I have attached a screenshot so you can see the "tools" button I am referring to]

This is the code I have so far:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

function main() { 
    automateSearch();
}

async function automateSearch() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width:1288, height:800});
    await page.goto('https://images.google.com/');
    await page.type('.gLFyf.gsfi','dog' + ' transparent');
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    await page.click('.TYpZOd');//my attempt at clicking the button
    // End Puppeteer
    await browser.close();
}

main()
```

Comment: have you tried assigning the XPath value of the tools button and triggering a click on It?

Comment: how would I assign a XPath value? sorry I am very new to Puppeteer and JavaScript in general.

Comment: `await page.click('a[href="/preferences"]');`